# Alternative to createGlobalStyle from styled-components that can also be importable

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

we are currently loading Fonts and few other global styles like this:

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

export default createGlobalStyle`
  @font-face {
     font-family: 'Name';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 400;
     font-display: swap;
     src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/name/v12/iJWZBXyIfDnIV5PNhY1KTN7Z-Yh-B4iFU0U1Z4Y.woff2) format('woff2');
  }

  // more fonts..
}
```

And in every `_app.tsx` (from every project in repo) we just

```
import GlobalStyle from @our-company/ui;
// few other imports

const AppProviders = ({ children, messages, locale }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <IntlProvider
      locale={locale || 'en-GB'}
      key={locale}
      messages={messages[locale]}
      defaultLocale="en-GB"
    >
      <GlobalStyle />
      <DsThemeProvider
        locale={locale}
      >
        {children}
      </DsThemeProvider>
    </IntlProvider>
  );
};
```

But we noticed unnecessary font reloads caused by this `GlobalStyle` when clicking, for example, in checkbox elements (tried putting this in a .css and just load it and never happens again).

Any idea how could export this styles as `GlobalStyle` name without using styled-components so we don't have to change all `import` from all apps in the project?

Comment: would replacing the styled-components `createGlobalStyle` with a component that imports the font configuration from a css file be ok by you?

Comment: not quite, I'm trying not to refactor all apps in the repository (there are plenty)

Comment: I mean replace `GlobalStyle` from @our-company/ui with a component that imports its styles from a css file thus making it "static" instead of reloading every time, am I clearer now?

Comment: that's exactly it! thanks for putting it in understandable words 

Comment: ahh ok good, so that would help?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Can you explain clearly what is exactly your problem?

Comment: @MasihJahangiri Fonts reload on state change

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet did my proposed option answer your question?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli not quite, the idea is not having to refactor all apps in repo, only this file

Comment: yea that's right, you'll edit the file as I suggested in you import from here `import GlobalStyle from @our-company/ui;` (the first file where you used `createGlobalStyle`) then import it as you did before

Comment: @NoamYizraeli so would you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

why you dont create main.css and import it on your index.css or app.css , its download and cache on users browser so you don't need to use global styled component anymore

Comment: I'm trying not to re-factor all apps in the repository if possible.. ^^

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for something like [`injectGlobal`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/3e5d63fd71ad06c37cfb5fe6bc8e77553ddc0fb2/docs/css-we-support.md#css-we-support):

```js
import { injectGlobal } from 'styled-components';

injectGlobal`
  /* your @font-face stuff here */
`
```

This seems like it would be a good fit for your situation, as it would be relatively easy to transition from the existing structure using `createGlobalStyle` to one that uses this.

In your case, the code would look like:

```js
import { injectGlobal } from 'styled-components';

injectGlobal`
  @font-face {
     font-family: 'Name';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 400;
     font-display: swap;
     src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/name/v12/iJWZBXyIfDnIV5PNhY1KTN7Z-Yh-B4iFU0U1Z4Y.woff2) format('woff2');
  }

  // more fonts..
}
```

If you wish to use a solution that is backwards-compatible with any code that is rendering `<GlobalStyle />`, you can include a null component as the default export as a stop-gap solution, alongside your `injectGlobal` code:

```js
export default () => null;
```

Would this solve your problem?

Comment: I can not get it working, could you post how the whole file should look? this is my current test https://pastebin.com/dc3u4xmi  and it explodes hehe

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet your exported component is wrong – it should be just `const GlobalStyles = () => null;` as I suggested above. Trying to render `injectGlobal` will be no good.

Comment: still doesn't work.. https://pastebin.com/tLNMkDvz `"export 'default' (reexported as 'GlobalStyle') was not found in './fonts'`

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet keep the `export default GlobalStyle;` or otherwise it cannot be imported by other files.

Comment: have you tried it? `wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully
error - Error: Cannot create styled-component for component: `

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind the style directly inside the JS file

```
var stylingObject = {
  div: {
    color: "red",
    border: "1px solid red"
  }, input: {
    margin: "2px",
    padding: "5px"
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
      <div style={stylingObject.div}>
        <input style={stylingObject.input} type="text" />
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally I had hoped to import some CSS file with the fonts defined there and then just importing it so it would affect the entire page, obviously because the way react works such a thing isn't possible cause it would take place only in the imported component not in the one that did the import.

the reason `createGlobalStyle` from styled-components renders each time is also due to react's workings - when we set the style for a "component like" (or actual component) object, like every react component its not static and renders only when needed. Even if we make it render by force on page load its not the same one (cause on each page we render it separately) so keeping up with the current config doesn't seem to be possible by react's standard.

If we want to make the styles static or "more" static we would have to :

- either import them in each page separately - making us do a major refactor
- or use either `createGlobalStyle` (allowing us to use our already created styled-components component) or importing a main css file in the main application component like in the example below:

globalStyles.js

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
 
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: teal;
    font-family: Open-Sans, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  }
`;
 
export default GlobalStyle;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import GlobalStyle from './theme/globalStyle';
import Content from './components/Content';
 
function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Content />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

Comment: But that's exactly how we have the code currently (you can see it in the question) (I think you forgot to add this code? "or importing a main css file in the main application component like in the example below")

Comment: The difference here is you use the styled-component (createGlobalStyle) but you use it in the app main component instead of in specific components thus saving having to reload depending on the main component (like a navbar) to render the same thing at all times and stay through the lifetime of the application

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet if this answer helped you please accept it

Comment: Sorry but I can't see how it helps vs my current code..

Comment: if you import it only in the main component it would be rendered from the start eliminating the rerenders on each new component

Comment: please have look at our `_app.tsx` (looks like very different from it)

Comment: from how its defined [here](https://github.com/resir014/nextjs-typescript-quickstart/blob/master/pages/_app.tsx) it looks possible

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rather large global stylesheet like we did while migrating, you can use styled-components `css` method to leverage styled-components (css) IDE syntax highlighting & linting you can also do the following:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { createGlobalStyle, css } from 'styled-components'

const Reset = css`
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
`

const Accessibility = css`
  .hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
`

const BaseStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  ${Reset};
  ${Accessibility};
`

export const GlobalStyles = () => (
  <>
    <BaseStyles />
  </>
)
```

> Import GlobalStyles and render as sibling to `{children}`